# generating drop down asp.net mvc code first

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first

I have a model class;

```
namespace myapp.Models
{    
    public class karyakramModels: CommonModels
    {
        [Key]
        public int KaryakramId { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public int karyakramType { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [MinLength(5)]
        public string KaryakramName { get; set; }       
    }
}
```

I have to create a drop down from this model class in another vie model class.

```
namespace myapp.ViewModels
{
    public class NikashaViewModels
    {

        public int NikashaType { get; set; }
       
        [Required]
        public decimal NikashaAmount { get; set; }
        [Required]

        public int KaryakramId { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<karyakramModels> karyakrams { get; set; }        
    }
}
```

In my `create.chtml` page, the drop down code is

```
@model myapp.ViewModels.NikashaViewModels

...


  <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.KaryakramId, "KaryakramId", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KaryakramId, new SelectList(Model.karyakrams, "KaryakramId", "KaryakramName"))
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.KaryakramId, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

But I am getting error as: `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`
in the line `@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.KaryakramId, new SelectList(Model.karyakrams, "KaryakramId", "KaryakramName"))`

My controller method to get the list of karyakram list.

```
private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        public ActionResult New()
        {
            
            var viewModel = new NikashaViewModels
            {
                karyakrams = db.karyakrams.ToList()
            };

            return View(viewModel);
        }
```

What is wrong with the code?

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, the problem is your `IEnumerable` in your `SelectList` is null. Try to debug this line and make sure this is not empty or else it will trigger the same error message:

```
karyakrams = db.karyakrams.ToList()
```

Make sure your table `karyakrams` contains data.

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller to

```
public ActionResult New()
    {
        
        var viewModel = new NikashaViewModels
        {
            KaryakramId = 0,
            karyakrams = db.karyakrams.ToList()
        };

        return View(viewModel);
    }
```

(it needs to be initialized)